# Passing async values from a function into a transporter

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

My code:

```
 async function accessSecretVersion() {
  const [version1] = await client.accessSecretVersion({
    name: email,
  });
  const [version2] = await client.accessSecretVersion({
    name: pass,
  });

  let payload = {
    user: version1.payload.data.toString(),
    pass: version2.payload.data.toString()
  }
  return payload;
}


const mySecrets = accessSecretVersion();

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(mySecrets.then(function (result) {
  const emailEnd = result.user
  const passEnd = result.pass
  console.log(emailEnd) // check = getting email 
  console.log(passEnd) // check = getting password 

  return {
    emailEnd,
    passEnd
  };

}, {
  host: 'email host',
  port: port,
  auth: {
    user: emailEnd,
    pass: passEnd,
  },
}));
```

I'm trying to pass the values from 'emailEnd' to user: 'emailEnd' etc
but as I expected, I get the error

```
'ReferenceError: emailEnd is not defined'
```

I am new to javascript, and I know this is probably a really long way of trying to achieve what I need to but I just can't get my head around passing the values from function to function.

Thanks for any help or direction in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to `mySecrets.then` must be a function that handles errors, but it is an object literal `{host: ...}`. And this object literal refers to an undefined variable `emailEnd` (which is only a local variable in the function that is the first argument to `mySecrets.then`).

What you want is probably something like

```js
async function init() {
  const transporter = await mySecrets.then(function (result) {
    return nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: 'email host',
      port: port,
      auth: {
        user: result.user,
        pass: result.pass
      }
    });
  });
  // Do something with transporter.
}
```

Note that the `transporter` assignment is an asynchronous statement, because `mySecrets` is already asynchronous. You therefore have to place the assignment statement in another `async function`, depending on what you want to do with the `transporter`.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I tried similar before, and now I'm getting  

const transporter = await mySecrets.then(function (result) {
                    ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Comment: That's what I meant by "place in another async function". See my edited answer.

Comment: That worked :-) thank you for the help. I have other errors now I need to sort through. That was great thank you